# Duplicate Meta Descriptions after 301 Redirects

Tags: redirect, duplicates, meta, google-search-console

This summer we changed our site and link structure from
domainname.com/blog/category/post-name to
domainname.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory/post-name

For now they are working fine every link redirects (I only have some tags that are not found).

But my problem is Duplicate Meta Description on some of those links. If I access the old link it redirects me to the new one (So the redirect works), but i have this error, with duplicate meta description.

Should I worry about it? And Alo Duplicate Meta Title tags.

Answer (score 1):

These are most likely old errors in Google Webmaster Tools. However, it's also possible that the redirecting pages still contain a meta description which Google can read. Make sure the pages contain a 301 redirect and nothing else.

Comment: They are posts, not pages. The old posts do not exist anymore physicaly, only their content is available on the new posts. I have over 2000 redirected posts, and do not know why only 100 of duplicate meta description. And last updated was on 6 Jan 2014

Comment: If it has a unique url it's a page. Even though they don't exist, there's a server response on the old url (which serves the redirect). Make sure that redirect page is clean.

Comment: What do you mean by clean?

Comment: On a post I have a <meta name="description" content="bla bla"> and a <meta property="og:description" content="bla bla">. Does that count for duplicate meta description?

Comment: Could you give me a redirecting url?

Comment: This is one of my redirects rule that gives Duplicate Meta Description Redirect 301 http://www.247airporttransfer.co.uk/blog/taxi-transfer-from-swanley-br8-to-heathrow-airport/ http://www.247airporttransfer.co.uk/destinations/kent/swanley-br8/taxi-transfer-to-heathrow-airport-from-swanley/